# QtCreator Debug build yet PC jumps around

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, gdb, qt-creator

Within QtCreator, in an Ubuntu machine, I want to debug a C++ application. 
I make a debug build by adding -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug argument to the CMAKE part of the build settings. I set a breakpoint and I start debugging. The breakpoint is hit, but instead of stepping through the code linearly, the program counter (PC) keeps jumping around like it I was trying to debug optimized code, yet it's a debug build. The program is multi-threaded but I've verified that while debugging I am in the same thread, and yet the PC keep jumping to lines unrelated to the code.

Why could this happen? how to avoid it?

I suspect if this behavior may be related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631187/how-to-debug-cuda-program-with-multiple-threads) I made a while ago debugging with gdb. Unfortunately, the question went unanswered and I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: Perhaps your `CMakeList.txt` file adds optimization regardless of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`? And have you cleaned out the CMake cache between calling CMake?

Comment: You were right! there was set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, ...) in CMakeList.txt that was setting -O3. I used -Og instead and I could step as expected. I tried to use CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE to handle the build options but this has been a string of problems, probably another SO question.

Comment: If you make your comment a question I'll accept it.